# Embedding the Java h2 database programmatically

Tags: java, database, embedding, h2

At the moment we use [HSQLDB](http://www.hsqldb.org/) as an embedded database, but we search for a database with less memory footprint as the data volume grows.

[Derby / JavaDB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/) is not an option at the moment because it stores properties globally in the system properties. So we thought of [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

While we used HSQLDB we created a Server-object, set the parameters and started it. This is described [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html#N10BBC) (and given as example in the class org.hsqldb.test.TestBase).

The question is: Can this be done analogous with the h2 database, too? Do you have any code samples for that? Scanning the h2-page, I did not find an example.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the download, I see that the file tutorial.html has this

```
import org.h2.tools.Server;
...
// start the TCP Server
Server server = Server.createTcpServer(args).start();
...
// stop the TCP Server
server.stop();
```

Answer (score 73):

Yes, you can run H2 in embedded mode.  You just use the JDBC driver and connect to an embedded url like this (their example):

> This database can be used in embedded
>   mode, or in server mode. To use it in
>   embedded mode, you need to:
>
> ```
> * Add h2.jar to the classpath
> * Use the JDBC driver class: org.h2.Driver
> * The database URL jdbc:h2:~/test opens the database 'test' in your user home directory
> ```

Example of connecting with JDBC to an embedded H2 database (adapted from http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbcx/JdbcDataSource.html ):

```
import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;
// ...
JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
ds.setURL("jdbc:h2:˜/test");
ds.setUser("sa");
ds.setPassword("sa");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

If you're looking to use H2 in a purely in-memory / embedded mode, you can do that too.  See this link for more:

- http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases

You just need to use a special URL in normal JDBC code like "jdbc:h2:mem:db1".

Comment: I need to set the "properties" right, to say: I have to - at least - set the directory the database resides in. This is the reason why we cannot use Derby/JavaDB because it uses system properties, as stated in the question.

Comment: Running on port 8082, which defaults for h2 is no option, either.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  Nothing here uses system properties.  You specify a place to store files.  It's up to your app to decide where to do that.  You can use java.io.tmpdir for that if you want.  It doesn't run on a port in embedded mode.

Comment: I'm modding this back up - Alex's answer is dead on accurate.  Is the OP unclear on how to establish a JDBC connection using a driver class and URL?  Let's get some clarification, and maybe Alex would be willing to provide some actual code that uses these parameters.

Comment: I added the JDBC connection code.  Just vanilla JDBC usage though.  @Georgi, are you looking for a pure *in-memory only* database?  Maybe there is confusion here over what "embedded" means.  To me that means "in process engine" not "in memory data".

Comment: I needed a soulution that gives you the possibility to start the h2 server in an other application, and I needed to get a hand on all the parameters too (both "programmatically"). The solution of @anjanb is best: Create a org.h2.tools.Server-object and put params into - just what I exactly asked for

Comment: @AlexMiller - Is this database created on the harddisk or ram ? I am trying to find the location of the test database file on my harddisk.

Comment: @AlexMiller - Okay, so I did a simple test to find out if the table is in RAM or harddrive. It seems to be in harddrive. Reason - I ran my code and it created a db with table. Then, I ran the code again and it tells me that the table already exists. Now, how do I find the location of the DB in my harddrive ?

Answer (score 5):

If for some reason you need an embedded H2 database in server mode you can do it either manually using the API
at http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html - or by
appending ;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE to the database URL.