# What is the best database to use for a Java desktop application

Tags: java, database, firebird

Which of the following databases is best for a big desktop application: Firebird, JavaDB, hsqldb ?
I need performance, easy of use, and totally free license.

Comment: This question has some good discussions too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're looking for an embeddable database, my recommendation would be [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) (stands for Hypersonic 2, (re)written by the author of HSQLDB). See the [detailed comparison of features](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#comparison) and of [performances](http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html).

Using a 100% Java database would allow to run it in the same process and make things a lot easier IMO.

Comment: @BalusC I have dropped hsqldb and javadb in favor of H2, I just love it. And its [compatibility mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) (it can "behave" like, say Oracle, DB2, etc) is wonderful for testing.

Comment: Hey, that's nice. I must admit that I didn't knew that it stands for Hypersonic 2. That will be a new toy to play with sooner or later :)

Comment: +1 The project is well maintained, and the author often participates in http://groups.google.com/group/h2-database

Comment: How does H2 compare to Derby in this scenario?

Comment: Ok, my choice is between Firebird and H2, what's of this is better?

Comment: To EMBED a H2 db programatically - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154636/embedding-the-java-h2-database-programmatically

Answer (score 6):

Let me recommend you on **Postgres** (http://www.postgresql.org/
), which is one of the best freeware DB's I know.

I had an experience with this DB in my previous project, in which we held ~20 tables in the schema, the largest table had ~100,000 rows, and the amount of total data was not that big.

This project is running in production for more then 2 years, and there weren't any special problems with it.

Shay

Comment: If he's shipping a desktop application it's probably advantageous not to have users install a separate database application, hence the OP has given a suggestion of JavaDB and hsqldb, both of which can be embedded in Java applications. I'm not sure how Firebird fits into that though. Of course, this is in no way a dig at Postgres, which to my mind is the obvious choice whenever a database is required: Desktop or Server.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation is H2. I recently migrated a db (from MS SQL server) including 2 larger tables hosting >2 million rows each. First I tried Derby and had issues (not only performance) - then I switched to H2 and migrated everything successfully.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll be better off with an embeddable database for this.  HSQLDB or H2 would work, as would [SQLite](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/).  SQLite is quite popular outside the Java world (it's used by the Mozilla project, for instance).  I'm not familiar with JavaDB, so I can't speak to its capabilities.

SQLite is known to be pretty fast.

Answer (score 3):

[Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) is very good database especially for desktop application

There is good java driver.

Comment: Especially for 'big desktop applications'. Firebird scales to hundreds of gigabytes and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on requirements and data amount. My last choice was MySQL and it was very comfortable (swing app)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a DBMS that is *not* Java-specific.  You may want to share your data with a C++ or .NET application some day.  If it does not need to be client/server consider SQLite or H2.  If it does then consider Postgres.  All of these have ODBC drivers and/or drivers for specific languages other than Java.