# Converting a file to an accessible object

Tags: java, file, randomaccessfile

**Summary:**

I am trying to write a *utility* program that is based on the information contained in a separate file. The object has to be such that any information on the *physical file* can be retrieved quickly and can be updated quickly as well.

**Details:**

The file is a normal `ANSI` encoded file that is supposed to store definitions of the physical quantities stated in the SI system. What I *really want* is that I should be able to read and write changes to the definitions whenever required. I'll be using markers(like ":") to get the headings and definitions like:

```
Length:metre:m:"..length of path traveled by light in vacuum in 
1/299792458th of a second"
```

and so on.

So in this case **is extending `RandomAccessFile`** an option? Will it help me in quick retrieval and syncing of data? Should I use another approach?

Comment: I'd just use an embedded database like H2 to be honest

Comment: @EnnoShioji Perhaps a little more info?

Comment: HTH means "Hope this helps" :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want these things, then I'd advise you to use an embedded ACID database like H2:

- Guarantee that you don't lose changes that you made
- Have more than one program access the info

This is because coding up something that correctly does this using low level facilities like `RandomAccessFile` is quite hard. Storing persistent application state in embedded DBs is commonly done. H2 is probably the most popular among DBs implemented in pure Java.

On how to actually do this, see this: [Embedding the Java h2 database programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154636/embedding-the-java-h2-database-programmatically)

You prob. want to look at introduction on relational DBs & SQL if you aren't familiar with them.