# Import H2 Database Engine into IntelliJ IDEA local server

Tags: java, database, maven, intellij-idea, h2

There is a local application that I use for testing purposes. It is running on an tomcat server that is executed via IntelliJ IDEA. Now I want to build an API that I can send a HTTP-Request to (something like http://%myAddress%:8123/rate) and then a new database entry is created. For the database I would like to use h2 database engine.

I have done some research on how to use h2 and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154636/embedding-the-java-h2-database-programmatically).

Now I tried to import that module. Since this is a maven application, I added a new dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.196</version>
</dependency>
```

And then I created a new class where I want to initialize the Database structure:

```
package mypackage;

import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;

public class DataBaseInitializer {

    public DataBaseInitializer() {

    }

}
```

Sadly the import is failing, since he `Cannot resolve symbol 'h2'`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you verify the H2 jar hit downloaded and is now present within your IntelliJ project? If it is not, you may not have set Maven to "auto-import", that is, react to your addition of another dependency in the POM file. You will need to trigger Maven now to do its thing (download the jar).

Answer (score 0):

`org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataServer` doesn't seem like a correct class. Check [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbcx/JdbcDataSource.html) documentation. The `org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource` class is used for creating the data source.